# Update a File name in File Transfer activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi

Im trying to update Data Extract and File Transfer activities with dynamic file names. I could complete my use case for Data Extract acticity and was able to update file name in Data Extract using REST api call within ssjs. Currently im stuck with File Transfer part. Im not even sure where to start. Does anyone have tried updating File Transfer activities via ssjs / rest / soap api. If so can you add you inputs here (like api endpoints / payload if in case of api call).